# Convert time string in XSLT

Tags: xslt

How do I convert a time string like

```
20101115083000 +0200
```

to

```
2010-11-15 08:30:00 +0200
```

using XSLT?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

We use templates:

```
<xsl:template name="format-date-time">
    <xsl:param name="date" select="'%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%z'"/>
    <xsl:value-of select="substring($date, 9, 2)"/>
    <xsl:text>/</xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="substring($date, 6, 2)"/>
    <xsl:text>/</xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="substring($date, 1, 4)"/>
    <xsl:text> </xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="substring($date, 12, 2)"/>
    <xsl:text>:</xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="substring($date, 15, 2)"/>
    <xsl:text>:</xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="substring($date, 18, 2)"/>
</xsl:template>
```

We call these templates like this:

```
<xsl:call-template name="format-date-time">
    <xsl:with-param name="date" select="./Startdate"/>
</xsl:call-template>
```

./Startdate is an XML date, but with the substring technique, I think you could solve your problem too.

Answer (score 2):

If you have XSLT 2.0, you can use [date parsing and formatting functions](http://www.w3.org/TR/xquery-operators/#func-dateTime).

If you have XSLT 1.0, but can use EXSLT, it provides [similar functions](http://www.exslt.org/date/index.html).

These would be less transparent to use than @Peter's explicit code, but maybe more robust if your input format can vary.

Answer (score 2):

**Here is a most generic formatDateTime processing**. Input and output format are completely configyrable and passed as parameters:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

 <xsl:template match="/">
  <xsl:call-template name="convertDateTime">
   <xsl:with-param name="pDateTime" select="."/>
  </xsl:call-template>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template name="convertDateTime">
  <xsl:param name="pDateTime"/>
  <xsl:param name="pInFormat">
    <year offset="0" length="4"/>
    <month offset="4" length="2"/>
    <day offset="6" length="2"/>
    <hour offset="8" length="2"/>
    <minutes offset="10" length="2"/>
    <seconds offset="12" length="2"/>
    <zone offset="15" length="5"/>
  </xsl:param>

  <xsl:param name="pOutFormat">
   <y/>-<mo/>-<d/> <h/>:<m/>:<s/> <z/>
  </xsl:param>

  <xsl:variable name="vInFormat" select=
   "document('')/*/xsl:template[@name='convertDateTime']
                       /xsl:param[@name='pInFormat']"/>
  <xsl:variable name="vOutFormat" select=
   "document('')/*/xsl:template[@name='convertDateTime']
                       /xsl:param[@name='pOutFormat']"/>
  <xsl:apply-templates select="$vOutFormat/node()"
       mode="_convertDateTime">
    <xsl:with-param name="pDateTime" select="$pDateTime"/>
    <xsl:with-param name="pInFormat" select="$vInFormat"/>
   </xsl:apply-templates>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="y" mode="_convertDateTime">
  <xsl:param name="pDateTime"/>
  <xsl:param name="pInFormat"/>

  <xsl:value-of select=
     "substring($pDateTime,
                1+$pInFormat/year/@offset,
                $pInFormat/year/@length)"/>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="mo" mode="_convertDateTime">
  <xsl:param name="pDateTime"/>
  <xsl:param name="pInFormat"/>

  <xsl:value-of select=
     "substring($pDateTime,
                1+$pInFormat/month/@offset,
                $pInFormat/month/@length)"/>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="d" mode="_convertDateTime">
  <xsl:param name="pDateTime"/>
  <xsl:param name="pInFormat"/>

  <xsl:value-of select=
     "substring($pDateTime,
                1+$pInFormat/day/@offset,
                $pInFormat/day/@length)"/>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="h" mode="_convertDateTime">
  <xsl:param name="pDateTime"/>
  <xsl:param name="pInFormat"/>

  <xsl:value-of select=
     "substring($pDateTime,
                1+$pInFormat/hour/@offset,
                $pInFormat/hour/@length)"/>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="m" mode="_convertDateTime">
  <xsl:param name="pDateTime"/>
  <xsl:param name="pInFormat"/>

  <xsl:value-of select=
     "substring($pDateTime,
                1+$pInFormat/minutes/@offset,
                $pInFormat/minutes/@length)"/>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="s" mode="_convertDateTime">
  <xsl:param name="pDateTime"/>
  <xsl:param name="pInFormat"/>

  <xsl:value-of select=
     "substring($pDateTime,
                1+$pInFormat/seconds/@offset,
                $pInFormat/seconds/@length)"/>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="z" mode="_convertDateTime">
  <xsl:param name="pDateTime"/>
  <xsl:param name="pInFormat"/>

  <xsl:value-of select=
     "substring($pDateTime,
                1+$pInFormat/zone/@offset,
                $pInFormat/zone/@length)"/>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when this transformation is applied to the following XML document**:

```
<dateTime>20101115083000 +0200</dateTime>
```

**the wanted, correct result is produced**:

```
   2010-11-15 08:30:00 +0200
```

Comment: Thanks, but as I'm quite new to XSL, I prefer a simpler solution ;)

Comment: @blugray: Except that every time the input format and the desired output format change you will have to write - again and again new xslt code and debug it. What I am posting here is just a single solution for all such cases -- never write any more xslt code to format a datetime.