# Converting timestamp to UTC timezone with XSLT

Tags: xslt

I have an XML that has timestamp in format like **2016-06-07T07:46:04**

I would like to convert timestamp in UTC format like **1465278364** using xslt

How can it be done?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert time string in XSLT](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4183956/convert-time-string-in-xslt)

Comment: So this seems most likely to be a "unix timestamp" i.e. the number of seconds  that have elapsed since 00:00:00 Coordinated Universal Time (UTC), Thursday, 1 January 1970 [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time) - how about find out the formula and implement it?

Comment: Can you use XSLT 2.0? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32975793/datetime-to-epoch-and-vice-versa-xslt/32977307#32977307

Comment: If available, this can be done with the [EXSLT function `date:seconds`](http://exslt.org/date/functions/seconds/index.html).

Answer (score 1):

I actually wrote a named template specifically for this a while back. Here it is:

```
<xsl:template name="converttime">
  <xsl:param name="date" select="."/>
  <xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="translate($date,'123456789','000000000') = '0000-00-00T00:00:00'">
      <xsl:value-of select="
        (
          ((substring($date,1,4) - 1970) * 365) + 
          floor((substring($date,1,4) - 1970) div 4) +
          substring(
           '000,031,059,090,120,151,181,212,243,273,304,334,365',
           substring($date,6,2)*4-3, 3
          ) +
          (substring($date,9,2)-1) +
          (1-floor(((substring($date,1,4) mod 4) + 2) div 3))*floor((substring($date,6,2)+17) div 20)
        ) * 86400 +
        (substring($date,12,2)*3600) +
        (substring($date,15,2)*60) +
        substring($date,18,2)
      "/>
    </xsl:when>

    <!-- Unknown format -->
    <xsl:otherwise>-1</xsl:otherwise>
  </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>
```

This adds up:

- The number of years since 1970, multiplied by 365.
- The number of leap years since 1970 (i.e., the number of leap days)
- The number of days since the beginning of the year for the given month (not accounting for leap years yet)
- The number of days since the beginning of the month
- 1 if it's a leap year and the month is March or later, otherwise 0 (this formula's fairly horrific, if you really want an explanation let me know in the comments and I'll break it down)

All of the above is then multiplied by the number of seconds in a day
Then it's just a simple matter of adding hours * (seconds in an hour), minutes * (seconds in a minute) and seconds.

You can support different date formats just by putting a different `<xsl:when>` element with a different date pattern, and obviously adjusting the substring calls to match.

Honestly though, only use this if you can't use XSLT 2.0 (or later) or an extension function. Also, I noticed the number you gave is 7200 seconds out from what this produces, but if you're in a time zone 2 hours different from UTC, that's probably why.

Comment: Interesting. A typo in translate($date,'123456789','000000000) missing quote. Do you have considered all leap year algorithms? if (year is not divisible by 4) then (it is a common year)
else if (year is not divisible by 100) then (it is a leap year)
else if (year is not divisible by 400) then (it is a common year)
else (it is a leap year)

Comment: I did, but the number of seconds since 1970 hits the maximum possible value in 2038 as it's typically a 32 bit number, so dates stored this way would never be affected.

Comment: Ah yes - it's a pity that libxml still only supports the 1.0 variant. If someone could provide the reversed template - timestamp to date - that would be great, too.

Comment: I had that somewhere- if I can find it, I'll edit it in here.